# PYTHON/NUMPY: How to assign various data types to the data type object numpy.dtype() in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I want to construct an numpy-array with various different data types using numpy.dtype() object.

I have a dictionary 'mydict' where all the information about the data is stored, I want to create a data type object `dt` with it. 'mydict' is dynamically created depending on which properties I am choosing and the data type is corresponding to the property as well!

```
import numpy as np

mydict={'name0': 'mass', 'name1': 'position', 'name2': 'ID', 
      'format0': np.float32, 'format1': np.int8, 'format2': np.uint64}
```

the data type object `dt` should look like this

```
dt = np.dtype([('mass', np.float32), ('position', np.int8), ('ID', np.uint64)])
```

**My question is how to create `dt` without constructing/writing it manually into the code?**

The main problem is that I do not know how to append `np.dtype()` with another entry of 'name' and 'format' combination or if that is even possible ...

I am using `dt` then to read my data into a numpy array like this!

```
data_array=np.array((nr_rows, nr_cols)), dtype=dt)
```

I tried certain attempts with Dict Comprehensions, lists and dictionaries but I could not find the right way to do that.

Comment: Where did you get the `dict`? You may want to construct it with your desired `dtype` in mind, so that you don't have to restructure it.

Comment: @Psidom: Hi, yes I want to do so, this dict is only an example!

Comment: Are the keys of the `dict` following a pattern as you are showing? `name[0-9]` and `format[0-9]`.

Comment: @Psidom: Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [209]: dd={'name0': 'mass', 'name1': 'position', 'name2': 'ID', 
     ...:       'format0': np.float32, 'format1': np.int8, 'format2': np.uint64}

In [213]: [(dd['name%s'%i],dd['format%s'%i]) for i in range(3)]
Out[213]: [('mass', numpy.float32), ('position', numpy.int8), ('ID', numpy.uint64)]

In [214]: dt=np.dtype([(dd['name%s'%i],dd['format%s'%i]) for i in range(3)])
In [216]: arr = np.zeros((2,), dt)
In [217]: arr
Out[217]: 
array([( 0., 0, 0), ( 0., 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('mass', '<f4'), ('position', 'i1'), ('ID', '<u8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your keys follow strict patterns as in the question, you can take a look at this; 1) extract values where the keys start with *name* and set them as the first element of the tuple; 2) replace *name* with *format*, and extract corresponding value as the second element of the tuple; 3) construct the dtype from the list of tuples.

```
import numpy as np
np.dtype([(d[k], d[k.replace('name', 'format')]) for k in d.keys() if k.startswith('name')])

# dtype([('position', 'i1'), ('ID', '<u8'), ('mass', '<f4')])
```

Note: you may need an [OrderDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) initially in order to have the right order of columns here.